# How to properly declare and fill columns within a database-like structure when starting with a data.frame with one column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am not an R newbie and also not a pro.
I can not solve nicely this problem.

Assume this structure:
surveys is a data frame with the following structure

```
surveys=data.frame(id=c(1L,3L,5L))
surveys
```

There are 3 survey IDs but assume I have a long list of 2000+ surveys

There also is a web which can get me an XML with some more info about the survey.
E.g., how many people participated, when it was done.
The full structure looks like this:

```
survey
-1 survey_id
-2 number of respondents
-3 names of respondents -  (each respondent has a first name and last name)
-4 when_done
-5 when_received
```

I want to add rows and dimensions to the surveys "data.frame" or (or list of lists)
which will be results of the web service call

So I do a loop like this

```
for (1:nrow(surveys))
{
  current=surveys$id[i]
  webout=getWebServiceResults(current)
    this will outputs a list of variables such as when_done, when_received)
  and now I want to store results  of the webservice calls into the surveys  structure by adding correct rows to surveys)
}
```

Assume that the webservice output is list and I can get when_received data by using `webout[[5]]`

1. Now how can I prior that loop, properly declare some new columns and declare their type as ISODate for example. Number of respondents as integer.

   I am used to work with databases. So I would just say alter table, add column with data type Date.

   How do I do it in R?
2. Also, how can put into survey object a substructure of differing length per survey (Person - with sub-fields like First_name and Last_name.

   In a database, I would create a separate linkage table with survey_ID and participant_ID and a another table with Participant_id and columns First_name and Last_name.

   But is there an elegant way in R to do this (e.g., data_frame column Participant is some sort of deeper structure? Do I have to stop using data.frame and convert surveys to a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
surveys<- data.frame(id=c(1L,3L,5L))

# Dummy, but returns a list with elements of correct types
getWebServiceResults <- function(id) list(id=id, foo=sample(letters,1), bar=runif(1))
set.seed(42)

r <- lapply(surveys$id, getWebServiceResults)
# r is now a list where each element is a row

# Create a 0-row data.frame with the correct column names and types
d <- data.frame(id=integer(), foo=character(), bar=numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Finally call rbind with the empty data.frame and all the rows...
d <- do.call(rbind, c(list(d), r))

d
#   id foo       bar
#2   1   x 0.9370754
#21  3   h 0.8304476
#3   5   q 0.5190959
```

...the trick is that the first argument to `rbind` must be a data.frame for this to work. Otherwise `rbind` will return a (weird) matrix.

**UPDATE** Regarding the second question about where to store the participants, I'd store them in a separate data.frame. All columns in a data.frame must have the same number of rows and it doesn't work well if they aren't of basic types (like numeric, character, date, factor). A column *can* actually be a matrix or even another data.frame, but it must have the same number of rows so it typically isn't very useful.

Comment: thx. This solves nicely the problem #1.

what about #2.
 How can I store the names of people on the survey. It is OK to use the list like you did in the first step (creating variable r). I think the target structure of a data.frame is not good for problem number 2.

Comment: @user984532 - Well, I'd keep the people in a separate table just as in a data base.